# How do I rewrite properly django and osqa htaccess to non www

Tags: django, .htaccess

Currently I put .htaccess on my `~/webapps/app/`with this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and it's worked to non-www, but the problem the URL will goes to `http://domain.com/osqa.wsgi/`

How do I remove the `/osqa.wsgi/`

Let me know

Answer (score 2):

That would only redirect the user back to the home page. Do this, it will keep everyone where they want to go. www to non-www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule osqa.wsgi/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want non-www to www Google it or just adjust line 3 and 4 to be like this example in reverse. domain.com should be your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "$1" argument from the last line. What this rule says is:
"When the host matches www.(anything)"
"Rewrite (the path part of the url) to http://(anything)/(the path part of the url)"
Where (anything) ends up as %1, and (the path part of the url) ends up as $1. So just remove the $1.